# Very, very slow PC when power button is pushed on due multiple auto startup wares

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, performance, desktop

I've got multiple background software that automatically popped-up during startup. Where is exactly the place to tweak this thing?

Many thanks.

Comment: need more information like which os, what are all the software pop-up's

Comment: So disable the auto-startup applications

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the Windows 8, 8.1, 10 then you can disable it easily by opening the 
**"Task Manager->Startup"**There you can select the application and disable it.If you found this as an answer make it in comment.

Comment: And for Windows 7, run msconfig, Startup (or something similar) tab then select Hide Microsoft Services. Note that there are other ways to run an app on startup, too. There is the delayed task scheduling. I use that to launch important apps after 2 minutes of a boot.